# Is there anyway to retrieve all keys that start with a particular string in redis?

Tags: javascript, redis

Is there anyway to retrieve all keys that start with a particular string in redis?

I want to do something like storing:

```
'thing1:userid1' : ' ';
'thing1:userid2' : ' ';
'thing2:userid1' : ' ';
'thing2:userid2' : ' ';
```

and retrieve every `thing1` without having to know every user.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
REDIS.keys("thing1:*")
```

However, you might want to consider using a map.

```
REDIS.hset("thing1", "user1", "")
REDIS.hset("thing1", "user2", "")
REDIDS.hgetall("thing1")
```

Do be careful with this in production. Redis can only process one command at a time, and KEYS is very slow. It has to look at every key in the entire database.

Comment: hey, yea i'm using a map right now but think it would be useful at a lower level since I only hgetall once in awhile. Just needed to make sure I could still get all the keys when needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [KEYS](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command in redis which search all of your key names for specified pattern. You should however be careful when using this command since it has O(N) time complexity, so the performance depends on amount of keys in your database. It is rather intended for debugging and not suitable for production environments.

Answer (score 1):

You can also keep track of the ids in a List and then retrieve the values of all keys ( or hashes ) using SORT http://redis.io/commands/SORT.

It's a bit more complicated than "KEYS" but it can do more as well ( :

I read somewhere that hgetall can give you problems if you have too many fields in a hash, unfortunately i can't find the reference atm.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/defunkt/redis-namespace

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command to iterate over all keys that matches given pattern:

```
> SCAN 0 MATCH thing1:*
1) "172032"
2) 1) "thing1:userid1"
   2) "thing1:userid2"
> SCAN 172032 MATCH thing1:*
1) "0"
2) 1) "thing1:userid3"
```